# Connect from locally to Redis on kubernetes cluster exposed through Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to contact a Redis container being up and running in a k8s pod.

The deployment of my container looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
        service: my-app
    spec:
      hostname: redis
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redis:6.0.19
          command:
          - redis-server
          env:
          - name: MASTER
            value: "true"
          ports:
          - containerPort: 6379
            name: redis
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "25m"
              memory: "256Mi"
            limits:
              cpu: "0.1"
```

There is Service on top of it:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
    service: my-app
  name: my-app
spec:
  ports:
    - name: redis
      port: 6379
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 6379
  selector:
    app: my-app
```

and I tried with the following Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: internal-nginx-controller-internet
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://oauth.internal.net/oauth2/start?rd=https://my-app.internal.net$uri
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://oauth.internal.net/oauth2/auth
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-app.net
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-app
          servicePort: 6379
```

The ingress in place works correctly because next to the Redis container there is another one spinning up an instance of my-app. I omitted it to make the question easier but the important bits is that it has it's own 9292 port, listed in the Ingress as well, under the same `path : /` and also exposed in the k8s Service. I am able to contact such service correctly through a url that looks like `<k8s-host>.my-app.net`. Instead when I try to contact Redis through a connection string like `redis://<k8s-host>.my-app.net/0` it hangs and gives me a connection timeout at the end. Any possible clue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ingress works in `layer 7`, and you are trying to connect using redis-client which uses `layer 4`. It does not work that way. You could use `LoadBalancer` [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) instead.

Comment: understood! May I ask you how did you know that redis-client works in `layer 4` ?